# Republish Hidden Service Descriptor to HSDir

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, torsocks, directory

Someone thought it would be funny to ddos my hidden service. Now my .onion domain after days of ddos stopping, and stop > start the tor service doesn't want to display. How do I republish my onion domain hidden service to new HSDir so it can be found by visitors?

Comment: It should do this automatically, but upvoted since I don't know why it's no longer working.